# Forward declaring a specific template instance

Tags: c++, templates, forward-declaration

I have a template that is just that - a very basic class template; something like:

Tmpl.h

```
template <typename Base>
class Tmpl: public Base
{
public:
    Tmpl(): Base()
    {
        this->methodOfBase();
    }
};
```

I would like to be able to forward-declare specialized versions of this `Templ`. I typically just store a (shared) pointer, so in my simple mind, all the compiler needs to know is that this is a pointer to a class; why am I not allowed to do this:

PublicClass.h

```
#pragma once
class MyClass;
class PublicClass {
    // ....
private:
    MyClass* test;
};
```

(I know pragma once isn't in the standard...)

PublicClass.cpp

```
#include "MyClass.h"
#include "Tmpl.h"

class SomeClass
{
public:
    void methodOfBase()
    {
    }
};

using MyClass = Tmpl<SomeClass>;

int main()
{
    PublicClass c;
    return 0;
}
```

On Visual Studio (2022) I get an error: `error C2371: 'MyClass': redefinition; different basic types`.

I know that as a workaround I can change `MyMethod.h` to

```
#include "Tmpl.h"

class SomeClass;
using MyClass = Tmpl<SomeClass>;

void myMethod(MyClass* test);
```

But I do not understand why the fact that MyClass is using a template needs to be visible to the users of PublicClass (all users of that class need to know about it).

I get that the compiler needs to know if a class is templated, i.e., needs a template parameter.  But in this case, `MyClass` is just an "instance" of a template, and shouldn't need special handling, or does it?

And what does the "different basic type" in the error refer to?

Comment: if possible you should make a [mcve] with all code in one file. As you have only one source and each header is only included once, it doesnt make a difference. Here it is: https://godbolt.org/z/dExsenx8z

Comment: Well, I guess I'm just thinking too complicated, thanks for the hints!

Comment: I think you can still forward-declare templates, so `template<typename Base> class Tmpl;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first declaration says that `MyClass` is a class.  The second one says that it is not, it is an alias. Those are different.

The problem is not realated to templates. You get the same error for

```
  class A;

  class B
  {};

  using A = B;
```

One possible workaround would be to let `MyClass` really be a class, but derive it from the template instance.

```
class MyClass;

class MyClass : public Tmpl<SomeClass>
{ };
```

Comment: what if `MyClass` should be just `Tmpl<SomeClass>`? Ie i want `std::is_same_v<MyClass,Tmpl<SomeClass>>`

Comment: Then you need the `using MyClass = Tmpl<SomeClass>;` version to be visible, and cannot forward declare the alias name as a class.

Comment: one of the cases where a simplified mental model of how C++ works breaks down completely. I mean it makes sense, but I wish it would be simpler ;)